# how to calculate height of the footer in a listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` and I have added to it a footer.  I am trying to get the height of the entire `ListView` including the footer programmatically, for that purpose i wrote the code posted below.

the problem I have now is, when I run the code
on any device with API level greater than 18, the code works fine. but if the API level of the device is 18 or less, the App crashes and I receive the below posted logcat error.

after investigation and debugging, i found that, when i work on a device with API level equals to 18 or below, there is something wrong that happens when the for-loops in the code section titled "`calcLisVieHeight`" reaches the last item in the list which is the footer.

therefore, i decided to split the same code into two parts. first part contains a for-loop that loops through the entire items in the list except the footer and then I added a code that only calculates the footers height to have
an idea how big is the height of the footer. so the code is as follows:

```
int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        int desiredHeight = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

        for (int i = 0; i < listView.getCount() - 1; i++) {
            View childView = listView.getAdapter().getView(i, null, listView);

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
                childView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            }

            childView.measure(desiredWidth, desiredHeight);
            height += childView.getMeasuredHeight();
            Log.v(TAG, "height: " + height);
        }

        ////////////////////calc footer height////////////////////////
        View childView = listView.getAdapter().getView(listView.getCount() - 1, null, listView);
        int heightFooter = 0;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            childView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }

        childView.measure(desiredWidth, desiredHeight);
        height += childView.getMeasuredHeight();
        heightFooter = childView.getMeasuredHeight();
        Log.v(TAG, "height: " + height);
        Log.v(TAG, "heightFooter: " + heightFooter);

        //dividers height
        height += listView.getDividerHeight() * listView.getCount() + childView.getHeight();
```

when i ran the above code without the code responsible for calculating the height of the footer the App works fine but it crashes generating the below logcat messages when i activate the code that claculates the height of the footer

please let me know how why the height of the footer cant be calculated and how to calculate it correctly

**calcLisVieHeight**:

```
switch (viewId) {
        case R.id.versicherungsListeActivity2mod_lisVie_versDetails:

            heightInPix = this.mLayoutDimsCtrl.calcLisVieHeight(listView);

            if (heightInPix != -1) {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, heightInPix);
                param.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, ruleSubject);
                container.setLayoutParams(param);
                listView.requestLayout();
            }
            break;
            ...
            ...
            ...


public int calcLisVieHeight(final ListView listView) {
......
......
int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
int desiredHeight = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

        for (int i = 0; i < listView.getCount(); i++) {
            View childView = listView.getAdapter().getView(i, null, listView);

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
                childView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            }

            childView.measure(desiredWidth, desiredHeight);
            height += childView.getMeasuredHeight();
            Log.v(TAG, "height: " + height);
        }

        //dividers height
        height += listView.getDividerHeight() * listView.getCount() + childView.getHeight();
        ......
        ......
        }
```

**logcat**:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
       at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1888)
       at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1857)
       at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:682)
       at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:748)
       at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1653)
       at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2447)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15204)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15204)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15204)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
       at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:2144)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15204)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15204)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15204)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
       at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:349)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15204)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15204)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2260)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2007)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6364)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I am not sure what other problems in your code because from different snippets of your code I don't see the entire picture but one thing for sure right now it crashes because you set `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` where it is expected to have `AbsListView.LayoutParams`, so first of all change RelativeLayout.LayoutParams to AbsListView.LayoutParams and then let's see what other problems you have.

Comment: @Vilen but when i run the same code on API > 18 it works fin without changing the RelativeLayout.LayoutParams to AbsListView.LayoutParams

Comment: @Vilen now after i tried your suggested answer i receive the following : java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams

Comment: 1. there is difference in listview implementation above and bellow api 18.
2. it is strange now you get reverse issue. I think you added changes in more than one place, try to change things one by one and see when error occurs. I would add an answer but I don't see enough from your code. would be good to see entire code.

Comment: Could you explain your motivation as to why you need the height of the content of your ListView? A ListView initializes its view lazily using view recycling, you shouldn't have to manually loop on its children. If you need the height of the footer for some purpose (like animation), you should probably focus only on the footer's view, most likely when you inflate it.

Comment: The entire point of a ListVIew is NOT to do things like this.  By calling getview on every item you're forcing each item to have a view created.  This totally destroys the entire point of view recycling.  At that point you're better off just manually adding each item to a ScrollView and not using a ListView at all-  you're actually currently less efficient than either of those two options.

Comment: @GabeSechan i think you are right..i solved the problem few days ago by creating a sparate view for each item and added them to the layout alloted for them

Answer (score 0):

Use this class as your CustomListView to achieve what you want. Hope it will work for you.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MyListView extends ListView {
public MyListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int heightSpec;

    if (getLayoutParams().height == LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) {
        // The great Android "hackatlon", the love, the magic.
        // The two leftmost bits in the height measure spec have
        // a special meaning, hence we can't use them to describe height.
        heightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    } else {
        // Any other height should be respected as is.
        heightSpec = heightMeasureSpec;
    }

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightSpec);
}
}
```

`

Comment: but my list adapter extends BaseAdapter and i cant override onMeasure

Comment: You can.......that's the adapter........you can easily customize your list view....

You want to put ListView under scrollview right?

Comment: my listview is already indside a scrollview ..but i cant overide onMeasure

Comment: you don't need to override the onMeasure() just use this custom ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong, but IMHO, reading your code, you should do the following:

Inside the `for loop` and wherever in your app you have to access the `footer` (last item in list so `index = length -1`) do a check for the `api lvl`.

```
if(currentIndex == footerIndex && currentApiLVL <= 18) //obv replace with the correct code, I don't have a compiler atm
{
  myFooterView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
} else {

  myFooterView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

so, you have to check **first** *if the item is the footer* (last item) and **also** *if the version is <= 18*. In that case, *and only in that case* (both conditions) you have to set params as `AbsListView` and not as `RelativeLayout`.

Maybe not, but I hope this can help you. Please try my code and let me know if this helped :)